# Let $ϕ: R → S$ be a ring homomorphism, where $S$ is a domain. Prove that if $u ∈ R$ is nilpotent then $u ∈ \ker ϕ$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation

Let $ϕ: R → S$ be a ring homomorphism, where $S$ is a domain. Prove that if
$u ∈ R$ is nilpotent then $u ∈ ker ϕ$.

Solution:
Suppose that $n ∈ N$ and $u^n = 0_R$. Then $0_S = ϕ(0_R) = ϕ(u^n) = ϕ(u)^n = ϕ(u)^{n−1}ϕ(u)$, so either $ϕ(u) = 0_S$ or $ϕ(u)^{n−1} = 0_S$ since $S$ is a domain. Repeating this, we eventually find that $ϕ(u) = 0_S$ and so $u ∈ \ker ϕ$.

I don't understand how "Repeating this, we eventually find that $ϕ(u) = 0_S$ and so $u ∈ \ker ϕ$." Could someone show me how you repeat it to get the final answer?

Comment: Either $\phi(u)=0$ or $\phi(u)^{n-2}=0$. Repeat now - either $\phi(u)=0$ or $\phi(u)^{n-3}=0$. Repeat now. Either $\phi(u)=0$ or .... or $\phi(u)^1=0$.

Comment: It suffices to prove that the only nilpotent in a domain is zero, because ring homomorphisms obviously preserve nilpotents.

Comment: For a nontrivial application see [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/83886/242) that a polynomial $p(x)$ is a unit (invertible) $\iff p(0)$ is a unit and all other coef's are nilpotent.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$0=\varphi (u)^{n-1}=\varphi (u)^{n-2}\varphi (u).$$

Comment: So would I just say either $φ(u)^{n−2}=0$ or $φ(u)=0$ and then conclude that $φ=0$ ?

Comment: No, if $\varphi(u) = 0$ you are done, otherwise repeat another time. And keep doing until you can't continue.

Comment: But you can repeat it infinitely many times because n doesn't have a limit? You would have to do it until you get $φ(u)^{n-n}φ(u)=0$

Comment: @Sarah: No, you can do it at most $(n-1^{th}$ time. Remermber that $n$ is fixed.

Comment: What do you mean by $n-1^{th}$ time?

Comment: $n-1$ time.$ \ \ \ \ $

Answer (score 0):

Claim. Let $S$ be a domain. Let $r\in S$ and $n\geq 1$. If $r^{n}=0$, then $r=0$.

Proof. We prove by induction on $n$. If $n=1$, then we are done. Let $n\geq 2$. Then $r^{n-1}r=r^{n}=0$. So $r=0$ or $r^{n-1}=0$. If $r=0$, we are done. If $r^{n-1}=0$, then by induction hypothesis, we have $r=0$.

Using this claim, since $\phi(u)^{n}=0$, we have $\phi(u)=0$.